# Why is "this" in the event listener the window and not the element?

Tags: javascript, this

```
const input= document.querySelector('.search');

input.addEventListener('keyup', e=>{
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

This doesn't do what I expected, since I'm calling the event listener on the input. I figured 'this' would be the input, but instead it's referring to the window. I'm confused about why this is. If anyone can explain it that'd be great.

To solve this I created a function and passed it into the listener.

```
function value(){
  console.log(this.value)
}

input.addEventListener('keyup', value)
```

I'm still confused about why doing it this way allows 'this' to refer to the input.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Answer (score 3):

An arrow function `(() => {})` does not have its own dedicated context as `this` but inherits it from whatever scope it is defined in.

If you want to get the correct `this` then you need to define a "normal" function just like you did.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rebind `this` in arrow functions. With arrow function `this` is determined by lexical scoping (where the function was defined). You should use a regular function here:

```js
const input= document.querySelector('.search');
 

// use a regular function and this will be what you expect
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input class="search" />
```